# Having trouble updating my cart on my amazon clone project with JS

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

I have been working on building an amazon clone alongside a youtube tutorial, however I got stuck trying to update the quantity of cart with the items that are added. the set of code that is supposed to loop through the cart and add the quantities keeps returning two results, NaN and the actual desired quantity, the NaN is not letting it add. you will be able to notice that both of this results are for the same console log. also when i console.log the item in the cart itself it displays the item once but this empty object alongside it, again on the same console.log line. please see the snippet for comparison

the specific set of code i wrote hoping to update the cart is on the right side of the snippet above. the hole code if required is below.

```
let productsHTML = '';

products.forEach((product) => {
  productsHTML += `
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="product-image-container">
        <img class="product-image"
          src="${product.image}">
      </div>

      <div class="product-name limit-text-to-2-lines">
        ${product.name}
      </div>

      <div class="product-rating-container">
        <img class="product-rating-stars"
          src="images/ratings/rating-${product.rating.stars * 10}.png">
        <div class="product-rating-count link-primary">
          ${product.rating.count}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="product-price">
        $${(product.priceCents / 100).toFixed(2)}
      </div>

      <div class="product-quantity-container">
        <select>
          <option selected value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="product-spacer"></div>

      <div class="added-to-cart">
        <img src="images/icons/checkmark.png">
        Added
      </div>

      <button class="add-to-cart-button button-primary js-add-to-cart"
      data-product-id="${product.id}">
        Add to Cart
      </button>
    </div>
  `;
});

document.querySelector('.js-products-grid').innerHTML = productsHTML;

document.querySelectorAll('.js-add-to-cart')
  .forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const productId = button.dataset.productId;

      let matchingItem;

      cart.forEach((item) => {
        if (productId === item.productId) {
          matchingItem = item;
        }
      });

      if (matchingItem) {
        matchingItem.quantity += 1;
      } else {
        cart.push({
          productId: productId,
          quantity: 1
        });
      }

      let cartQuantity = 0;

      cart.forEach((item) => {
        cartQuantity += item.quantity;
      });
      console.log(cartQuantity)

      document.querySelector('.js-cart-quantity')
        .innerHTML = cartQuantity;
    });
  });
```